# How to display a HTTPS page with an iframe in Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I have a page in my Ionic app that displays a WebView (with an iframe) in it, the problem is that it works well only if is a normal HTTP web page, it doesn't work with almost any HTTPS page like Google, Twitter, etc. The only HTTPS page that seems to be working in the app is https://www.httpsnow.org/ for some reason.

The code line is simply this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/" height="400px" width="350px"></iframe>
```

I need to display HTTPS WebViews in my app, preferably without having to use Cordova's inappbrowser. Is there a way to do it with iframe or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most larger organizations, including Google, Twitter, etc. set an `X-Frame-Options` header to `SAMEORIGIN` to prevent framing, as it has been used abusively in the past.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

For security reasons, this is not something you can override.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set X-Frame-Options on the iframe. That is a response header set by the domain from which you are requesting the resource .

Try adding Cross-origin-allow in your source domain to accept all domains requests.

OR

Instead of an iframe, redirect the user to use your link on their browsers instead from the app (which is non user friendly).

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with an ionic app for a chatbot, connecting to a Django framework chatbot engine backend. For the view(s) in which it was secure to do so, we worked around this issue by decorating the view with:

```
@xframe_options_exempt
```

This drops the X-Frame-Options from the response headers.

Django docs info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses

There are other ways to resolve this issue more securely.